# git doesn't see a change in file between two branches

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I'm seeing a weird behavior in git between merging branches:

Branch b0 has my latest copy of file A. Branch b1 needs to be merged with b0. So I checkout b1 and try to run:

b1$ `git pull origin b0`

Since the files are different on b0 and b1, I should either see a merge statement or conflict when I try to merge b0 into b1. However, I don't see any such thing.

why is this happening /how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge b0 into b1, have you tried

```
git checkout b1
git merge b0
```